# How to terminate the whole program when one of two methods running in parallel returns a result?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Here is a simple example.
I am trying to find a maximum element in an incremented array which only contains positive integers. I want to let two algorithms run `find_max_1` and `find_max_2` in parallel, then the whole program terminates when one algorithm returns a result.

```py
def find_max_1(array):
    # method 1, just return the last element
    return array[len(array)-1]


def find_max_2(array):
    # method 2
    solution = array[0];
    for n in array:
        solution = max(n)
    return solution

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Two algorithms run in parallel, when one returns a result, the whole program stop
    pass
```

I hope I explained my question clearly and correctly. I find can use `event` and `terminate` in `multiprocessing`, all processes terminate when `event.is_set()` is `true`.

```py
def find_max_1(array, event):
    # method 1, just return the last element
    event.set()
    return array[len(array)-1]


def find_max_2(array, event):
    # method 2
    solution = array[0];
    for n in array:
        solution = max(n)
    event.set()
    return solution


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Two algorithms run in parallel, when one returns a result, the whole program stop
    event = multiprocessing.Event()
    array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9... 1000000007]
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=find_max_1, args=(array, event,))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=find_max_2, args=(array, event,))
    jobs = [p1, p2]
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    while True:
        if event.is_set():
            for p in jobs:
                p.terminate()
            sys.exit(1)
        time.sleep(2)
```

But not efficient. If there is a faster implementation to solve it? Thank you very much!

Comment: I suggest you go ask this on the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) website here on SE. Stack Overflow is for solving problems with code, not optimizing it :).

Comment: Are you aware that python has two built-ins called `min` and `max`?

Comment: Thank you all very much.  The example stated above is just a simplification of the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are doing, you are making **zombie** processes. In python, the multiprocessing library works a bit confusingly.**If you want to terminate a process, make sure you joined it**. In python multiprocessing guidelines, its clearly said.

> Joining zombie processes

> On Unix when a process finishes but has not been joined it becomes a zombie. There should never be very many because each time a new process starts (or active_children() is called) all completed processes which have not yet been joined will be joined. Also calling a finished process’s Process.is_alive will join the process. Even so it is probably good practice to explicitly join all the processes that you start.

**So consider using the join() keyword when using terminate().**